# Little-o-asymptotics: Is this correct?

Tags: analysis

Suppose

- $\mu>0$
- $c>0$

Moreover, suppose that $f\sim e^{-(2\mu+c)d}$ as $d\to\infty$.

> > Does this imply that
> >     $$
> > f=o\left(e^{-\mu d}\right)\text{ as }d\to\infty?
> > $$

Of course, we have that 
$$
e^{-(2\mu+c)d}=o\left(e^{-\mu d}\right)\text{ as } d\to\infty\tag{1}
$$
and by definition $f\sim e^{-(2\mu +c)d}$ as $d\to\infty$ means that
$$
f=e^{-(2\mu+c)d}+o\left(e^{-(2\mu +c)d}\right)\text{ as }d\to\infty\tag{2}.
$$
Moreoever, I would say that
$$
o\left(e^{-(2\mu +c) d}\right)\subset o(e^{-\mu d}), d\to\infty\tag{3}.
$$

So I conclude
$$
f=e^{-(2\mu+c)d}+o\left(e^{-\mu d}\right)\text{ as }d\to\infty\tag{4}.
$$
and hence
$$
f=o\left(e^{-\mu d}\right)+o\left(e^{-\mu d}\right)\text{ as }d\to\infty\tag{5}
$$

Is (5) correct?

If yes, does (5) already imply the statement? I don't know how to use this/ how to go on.

Comment: $o$ is not something you can manipulate algebraically. $2o(g)$ is meaningless.

Comment: Okay, then I would need some help to prove or disprove the statement.

Comment: $\lambda$ ?????

Comment: Oh, sorry. You are right, $\lambda$ is not needed here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the definition of $o$:
$$\frac{f(d)}{e^{-\mu d}} = \frac{f(d)}{e^{-(2\mu+c)d}} \cdot \frac{e^{-(2\mu+c)d}}{e^{-\mu d}} = \frac{f(d)}{e^{-(2\mu+c)d}} \cdot e^{-(\mu+c)d}$$
The first factor is bounded and the second one tends to $0$ by your assumptions. Therefore $f(d) \in o(e^{-\mu d})$.

Comment: Can you really use this? Because $e^{-\mu d}$ tends to $0$ as $d\to\infty$

Comment: $e^{-\mu d}$ is never equal to $0$, so you are free to divide by it.

Comment: Sorry, one more question. Why is the first factor bounded? I guess you are again  using the definition, this time of $\sim$, which here can be stated to be $\lim_{d\to\infty}\frac{f(d)}{e^{-(2\mu+c)d}}=1$?

Comment: @Rhjg Yes, you can just apply the limit to both factors if you want.